# Microsoft Graph's One Drive Content API with HTTP Status 200 response

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Sometimes Microsoft Graph's One Drive Content API does not return HTTP status 302, but HTTP Status 200.
Occurs occasionally from 8/26.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/root:/{file-name}.xlsx:/content HTTP/1.1
SdkVersion: Graph-dotnet-1.4.0
Authorization: bearer {token}
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache
Host: graph.microsoft.com
Connection: Keep-Alive


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 28 Aug 2020 03:20:43 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache
Location: https://{tenant-name}-my.sharepoint.com/personal/{user-name}_onmicrosoft_com/_layouts/15/download.aspx?UniqueId={unique-id}&Translate=false&tempauth={tempauth}&ApiVersion=2.1
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
request-id: {request-id}
client-request-id: {client-request-id}
x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"Japan East","Slice":"E","Ring":"2","ScaleUnit":"000","RoleInstance":"TY1PEPF00000CC9"}}
Content-Length: 0
```

Comment: I suspect this happens because your `bearer {token}` is expired.

Comment: HTTP Status 401 when the `bearer {token}` has expired.